# Would we want to show preference for tags using plural versions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Take [glue](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glue) for instance. That tag is fine on it's own but would it be better or make more sense if it was [glues](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glues). The ways I could support this would be:

1. The tag is not about one "glue" but more the category of all adhesives or "glues"
2. If the plural was in place it would not be any harder to find. If someone tried to use [glue](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glue)  it would autocomplete to [glues](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glues) [as answered here](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/a/40/44)

I am more trying to make a case for glues here. Not all word pluralize well and some work just find as it like [paper](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper). [papers](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/papers) seems wrong.

Comment: While I remember, I think `glue` and `adhesive` should be synonyms, but it hasn't come up yet.

Comment: @CreationEdge That had occurred to me as well. I also was not sure which should be a synonym of the other.

Comment: Tapes are also adhesives.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's 2 primary answers here, if we don't want a complicated "in some cases" scenario:

### Yes, we should use plural forms for tags.

Crayons, markers, needles, knives, hammers, etc.

Exceptions should be for words that don't quite sound right in plural form, such as "papers".

Comment: Ha. Papers was the example I thought of that didnt fit the bill either.

Comment: @Matt Yeah, I can only ever think of documents when it's "papers." Show me your papers!

Comment: For future reference, it is generally better to leave meta question to open discussion rather than posting all sides of the conversation yourself. You can certainly post whatever *you* feel about the issue, but leaving this to a more open format gives everyone a voice. It's not difficult to infer what the community wants from the conversation while allowing for the possibility that there's an issue we have *not* considered. **[Polling is generally not a good substitute for discussion](http://bit.ly/1g0BO6d)**. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Sounds good. I mean, I'm happy to delete these and restart (since there's not been much for activity), if that helps.

Comment: @CreationEdge Not necessary. Just raising the issue for future consideration and for those who are looking on.

Answer (score -1):

Since there's 2 primary answers here, if we don't want a complicated "in some cases" scenario:

### No, we should use singular forms for tags.

Crayon, marker, needle, paper, hammer, etc.

Exceptions should be for words that don't sound right in singular form, such as "knife"

Comment: I think it feels natural to  talk about crayons, markers, needles etc. I would think that most people don't have issues with a specific `crayon` but a style of crayons.