# Should we create a tag for "tool-selection"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I was looking back on [my question from before](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/326/199) and I was searching for a tag describing someone asking about the pros and cons and description of each tool in a category (the question was about tool choice for adhesives).

The original tag that I had in this question before @Catija suggested the new tag, `tool-choice`, could be a tag synonym of `tool-selection`.

Comment: Maybe "tool-selection"?

Comment: @Catija We can use tag synonyms.

Comment: Sure... but I personally feel that selection would be a more descriptive term.

Comment: @Catija Yes, it would be more descriptive... I'll change this post to `tool-selection` but add `tool-choice` as a synonym.

Comment: If the wiki excerpt includes the word choice, I don't think a synonym will be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Robert Cartaino's comment](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39/can-a-moderator-make-crochet-and-crocheting-synonyms#comment68_40) regarding another synonym request:

> During the private beta, everyone can create tags to help bootstrap the system. But once the site launches, only users with a sufficient reputation/experience can create new tags, so folks will be forced to use those we already have. If an experienced user is prompted to tag something [crocheting](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crocheting) but they ignore that and enter [crochet](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crochet) instead, they are just being obstinate... and the regular community vetting can weed out such willful disorganization. Bloated synonym lists only fill the tag lists with unnecessary shadow tags without ever teaching users which is correct.

I feel that a synonym named [tool-choice](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool-choice) isn't necessary.

Currently, if you type in "tool" in the tag field, [tool-selection](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool-selection) populates first, followed by [tool-identification](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool-identification). I'm not certain we'll have enough tags prefixed by "tool" to make so that [tool-selection](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool-selection) isn't the obvious tag.

Answer (score 0):

[tool-selection](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool-selection) already exists and fits the need of what you are looking for. Has some well received questions already as well. The wiki excerpt *currently* states:

> When you are not sure what tools would best suit a particular application or project.

In your question you were looking for adhesive choices so that works well as the options are relatively finite.

I propose we use that tag in the mean time. That tag has a lot of success over at Woodworking.SE and I think it will be fine here. Just need to be sure questions like this try and limit there scope. Like to a specific craft or a subset of tools to choose from etc.

I don't see a need for a synonym for [tool-choice](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool-choice) at the moment but if that changes we could revisit this.